# age calculator in python from date (mm/dd/yyyy) and print age in years only

Tags: python, date, calculator

Hello fiends i want to develop a application, for here i want to know the age calculator in python from date (mm/dd/yyyy) and print age in years only...

please give me a piece of code

thanks

```
import datetime
bday=input("Enter your Birthday as(mm/dd/yyyy): ")
today.today()
age=bday.year-today.year
print"age is :" age
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because StackOverflow isn't about _giving code_.

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you posted? What do you expect it to do and what does it actually do?

Comment: What kind of piece of code are you expecting, I find this lack of definition confusing

Comment: "Give me the code" questions are not on topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
from datetime import datetime

my_date = raw_input("Enter B'date in mmi/dd/yyyy format:")

b_date = datetime.strptime(my_date, '%m/%d/%Y')

print "Age : %d" % ((datetime.today() - b_date).days/365)
```